# Why isn't CASPT2 used in surface hopping simulations?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I will write what I think the answer is. I'd like someone to confirm and maybe explain in detail.

I think that since surface hopping dynamics simulates movements on PES, it has to calculate gradients in each step. Since gradient for CASPT2 method can be evaluated only numericaly, CASPT2 quantum mechanical base for surface hopping dynamics would make calculations imspossibly slow.

Is this correct?

Comment: 1) CASPT2 analytic energy gradients are available in some codes (e.g. in MOLPRO). 2) A quick look at surface hopping dynamics reveals that  nonadiabatic coupling terms has to be computed, which looks like an actual issue, since they seem to be not available in codes as of now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nonadiabatic couplings are available in Molcas 8, since you can optimize conical intersections with Molcas.

Comment: It probably comes a little late, but you might want to check this out!
https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02259